# SAS: SELECT...INTO causes a random single quote to be added to end

Tags: sql, sas

When I do a `SELECT...INTO` statement for a particular WHERE it causes there to be a random single quote at the end. I am using a proc sql through SAS to run the following

```
proc sql noprint;
    SELECT DISTINCT PrimaryAgent, PrimaryAgentName
       INTO :AgentID separated by '|', :AgentName separated by '|'
    FROM test.OUTPUT_REPORTDATATAB
    WHERE Region = "Western" AND District = "Saskatchewan";
quit;
```

AgentID will have all the values separated by | as usual but the AgentName will have a single quote on the end (e.g. test|test2|test3') when I go to do a %put.

This issue only happens for this combination of Region and District, any other combination is fine.

I did notice that this Region and District combo is sitting at the bottom of the dataset but I would imagine it would cause the same issue for both AgentID and AgentName if that was the root of the issue.

Any ideas on what might be causing this? Or any way I could remove this single quote?

I have tried `substr` and `translate` but as soon as I try to pass in my `&AgentName`. It breaks the function (says I'm missing a parentheses).

I have even tried adding an *escaped* and *non-escaped single quote* to the front so it at least has matching quotes but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: How many records match your query? What is average length of AgentID or AgentName field? SAS macro variables can only be 65K long.

Comment: 20 records match query, length of AgentID is 6 characters, AgentName varies but there are none more than probably 50 characters

Comment: Try changing the order of the query (so `test3` doesn't end up at the end).  Does the quote still appear there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the single quote is actually in the data - I think highly likely, particularly as you say it is the last row in the dataset; likely there is a quote in your input data - you can use `compress` to remove it.

```
proc sql;
    SELECT DISTINCT compress(PrimaryAgent,"'") , compress(PrimaryAgentName,"'")
    INTO :AgentID separated by '|', :AgentName separated by '|'
        FROM test.OUTPUT_REPORTDATATAB
    WHERE Region = "Western" AND District = "Saskatchewan";
quit;
```

Bingo, no single quote (Assuming single quotes aren't normally allowed in those fields).  If they are sometimes allowed in those fields, it's a stickier problem that requires more information from you to answer.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you aren't trying to put too many characters into a macro variable. Macro variables can only be 65K characters long.

SAS is NOT going to insert any characters that are not in your data. So if you see `test3'` as part of the value of your macro variable then that most be part of the value of the dataset variable you used to populate it with.

Check variables AgentID and AgentName for quotes.

If you don't find any then check for other non-printing characters that might be confused by the macro processor as quotes or look like quotes to you when printed to the LOG.

Comment: I did try looking at the data and there is no visible single quote in the data. The AgentName will never be more than 50 characters. How would I check for non-printing characters?

Comment: You can look for quote.  `IF indexc(AgentName,"'") THEN put AgentName=;` Personally I just look for anything that is not a normal 7-bit ASCII code.  `IF lengthN(compress(AgentName,collate(32,127)))>0 then put AgentName=;`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, very strange. Your code looks fine to me. And I created a similar (assuming here) dataset, ran your code on it, and I'm not getting any single quotes.

```
%put &agentName.;
```

for me, returns - exactly how I would expect.

```
Name 1|Name 3|Name 6
```

Can you post your ingoing dataset - or at least a few relevant records? Alternatively, here is the code I wrote - look and see if something is different from what you've got. But the useful chunk here is ripped 100% from your post (with a noprint added for testing).

```
data output_reportdatatab;
primaryAgent=1; primaryAgentName="Name 1"; region="Western"; District="Saskatchewan"; output;
primaryAgent=2; primaryAgentName="Name 2"; region="Eastern"; District="Saskatchewan"; output;
primaryAgent=3; primaryAgentName="Name 3"; region="Western"; District="Saskatchewan"; output;
primaryAgent=3; primaryAgentName="Name 3"; region="Eastern"; District="Saskatchewan"; output;
primaryAgent=3; primaryAgentName="Name 3"; region="Western"; District="Saskatchewan"; output;
primaryAgent=3; primaryAgentName="Name 3"; region="Western"; District="Saskatchewan"; output;
primaryAgent=4; primaryAgentName="Name 4"; region="Western"; District="Alberta"; output;
primaryAgent=4; primaryAgentName="Name 4"; region="Western"; District="Manitoba"; output;
primaryAgent=5; primaryAgentName="Name 5"; region="Eastern"; District="British Columbia"; output;
primaryAgent=6; primaryAgentName="Name 6"; region="Western"; District="Saskatchewan"; output;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    SELECT DISTINCT PrimaryAgent, PrimaryAgentName
    INTO :AgentID separated by '|', :AgentName separated by '|'
        FROM OUTPUT_REPORTDATATAB
    WHERE Region = "Western" AND District = "Saskatchewan";
quit;

%put &agentName.;
```